# Where do I paste Utterances <script> tag in Jekyll Minima theme?

Tags: javascript, github, jekyll, github-pages, blogs

I want to add comments on my Jekyll website with Utterances. I use Minima theme, so I don't have `_layout/post.html`.

I copied

```js
<script src="https://utteranc.es/client.js"
        repo="sanchoi0310/comments"
        issue-term="pathname"
        theme="github-light"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        async>
</script>
```

I thought I had to paste it in `_site/index.html`, but the comment window was not there and my `<script>` tag was automatically deleted.

Where do I paste Utterances `<script>` tag in Jekyll Minima theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the code in the Default layout file. Also, you can create a layout for your page in _layouts file

```html
<script src="https://utteranc.es/client.js"
        repo="sanchoi0310/comments"
        issue-term="pathname"
        theme="github-light"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        async>
</script>
```